# "Cannot load representation of type public.video" using PHPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, url, phpickerviewcontroller

Trying to allow user to upload video from camera roll using PHPickerViewController (eventually to firebase storage) which is why I'm trying to get the url, but I'm getting this annoying error:

> Error Domain=NSItemProviderErrorDomain Code=-1000 "Cannot load representation of type public.video" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot load representation of type public.video}

Here is some code:

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult])
    {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        guard let itemProvider = results.first?.itemProvider else { print("isbeingcalled"); return }
        
        itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.video.identifier)
        { (url, error) in
            guard error == nil else { print(error!); return /**Alert**/ }
            
            print(url!)
        }
```

I've seen some other posts saying it might be a bug, so if it is, then what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
UTType.video.identifier
```

To

```
UTType.movie.identifier
```

Comment: I've tried both, does not work.

Comment: Well it works for me. Can you tell me how to make it not work?

Comment: It gives me a longer error: `"Cannot load representation of type public.movie" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot load representation of type public.movie, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003598f30 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4101 "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6000035911d0 {Error Domain=PHAssetExportRequestErrorDomain Code=4 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6000035913b0 {Error Domain=CloudPhotoLibraryErrorDomain Code=1006 "Failed to download CPLResourceTypeOriginal" UserInfo=0x600002ec9b80 (not displayed)}}}}}`

Comment: Also note that you really should always call `canLoad` so you don't get into a crash situation. What if the user chooses a still image?

Comment: Ah. So this video is in the cloud?

Comment: The actual code compiles but the error is printed, i think that might be the confusion.

Comment: No, I'm not confused.

Comment: I've configured it as such `configuration.filter = PHPickerFilter.videos` and yes this video is in the cloud, within the user's camera roll, I'll try calling canLoad.

Comment: Well there you are then. You really should have revealed that little secret in the question.

Comment: What do I do for class?, (like UIImage.self or PHLivePhoto.self)

Comment: Wait, the user shouldn't be able to choose an image since the configuration will only display videos in their camera roll.